# Multiple IHostedService in a console app execution order and delay time

Tags: c#, asynchronous, console-application, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have two background services.One of them perform measurements via serialport and the other one called SettingsWorker fetching measurement settings(like number of sensors,modules,fetching delays and so on) and share it with via static variable.

```
public class MeasurementWorker : BackgroundService
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {

                    ....
                    await Task.Delay(_measurementSettings.MeasurementFetchPeriod, stoppingToken);
                }
             }

public class SettingsWorker : BackgroundService
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {

                    ....
                    await Task.Delay(_measurementSettings.MeasurementFetchPeriod, stoppingToken);
                }
             }
```

Here is my program class.

```
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<SettingsWorker>();
            services.AddHostedService<MeasurementWorker>();

        }).UseSerilog();
```

When my application starts all the time SettingWorker must be executed first and set shared static variable.In my observations ordering services.AddHostedService changes execution order when application starts.

If I add SettingsWorker in the first order is it guaranteed that it will be firstly executed background task ?

If there are multiple background services like in my case, when any service hasn't finished execution and not reach await Task.Delay line yet,could it possibly stop and another background service starts to run just because delay time has been reached.

Comment: I didn't get why you down voting? Please share reason when down voting.Is there any similar questions ? Or is it a broad topic? Or is it too simple to answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I did some experiments about overlapping invocations.I created two background services as follows.(BackgroundService2 is the same with BackgroundService1 except it logs as BackgroundService 2)

```
public class BackgroundService1 : BackgroundService
    {
        private int executionCount = 0;
        private readonly ILogger<BackgroundService1> _logger;
        private Timer _timer;

        public BackgroundService1(ILogger<BackgroundService1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"BackgroundService 1 start to work. Thread ID : {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} Count: {executionCount}");
                executionCount++;
                _logger.LogInformation($"BackgroundService 1 done work. Thread ID : {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} Count: {executionCount}");
                await Task.Delay(100, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
```

Here is snapshot of overlapping calls.
[image]

If we don't want to invoke a backgroundservice unless the previous call has finished we have to control it via static shared variable like ;

```
if (!numberOfActiveJobs==1) {
Interlocked.Increment(numberOfActiveJobs);
```

Although I didn't find a documentation about which background service works first when application starts up,it seems it depend on the registration order of background services.
Note (I also observed that thread which starts background job,finishes the job.Like:Thread 7 starts job,(can be possibly interrupted by another thread) thread 7 finishes job